# Correct way to match a leading space with sed (all of them)?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, whitespace

How to match a leading space with `sed` (all of them)? I'm not talking about leading tabs, but rather only on leading spaces.

From a small test I did in Nano this seems to be correct:

```
sed "s/^ //g"
```

Do you find something wrong with this method?

---

<sub>Note: "All of them" means all leading spaces in the document, in case there are 2 or more, and not just one.</sub>

Comment: `tab` is also IN `whitespace` category. `sed "s/^[[:space:]]//g"`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest So I should go through a paradigm change --- from now and long I shall say "space" for a simple space as with the SPACE key in my keboard and "whitespace" for any space in the general sense (space or tabulation), correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove leading spaces: `sed "s/^ *//"`

Remove leading whitespace: `sed "s/^[[:space:]]*//"`

Remove leading spaces and tabs: `sed "s/^[ \t]*//"` (works in GNU sed) or
`sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//'` (works with any `sed`) or `sed $'s/^[ \t]*//'` (in ksh/Bash/etc. to give a literal tab to `sed`)

As said in the comments, the `/g` specifier does nothing, as the beginning of line appears only once in the line, and even `/g` does not retry the pattern more than one. You'd need to add a conditional branch explicitly to repeat the substitution: `sed -e :a -e 's/^ //' -e ta`

---

`^ *` matches the empty string (no spaces) too, but that doesn't matter here. If you want to match lines that have at least one space, use `^  *` (double space) or `^ +` in extended regex. E.g. to change all indentations to exactly two spaces, use  `sed -e 's/^  */  /'` or `sed -Ee 's/^ +/  /'` (`-E` is supported in e.g. GNU and FreeBSD)

Comment: Note that `sed "s/^[ \t]*//"` works in GNU `sed` only if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment. Otherwise it strips `t`s and backslashes like other `sed` implementations.

Comment: I wonder what's difference btw spaces and whitespace by definition and why are they treated differently? In some case, `sed "s/^ *//" ` just works if I have one space, while in other case, say I extract the righthand side of a diff output(after `|<>`), I have to use 2nd one `sed "s/^[[:space:]]*//"` to do the job.

Comment: @OscarZhang, tabs and newlines are "whitespace" too, in addition to the space I get from the big wide button. `sed "s/^ *//"` removes just spaces, not tabs etc. `[[:blank:]]` would match spaces and tabs and `[[:space:]]` matches some other stuff too, even newlines (not that you'd see that easily with sed or grep)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using below awk command too

```
 awk '{gsub("^ *","",$0);print $0}' filename
```