# remove white space using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

In the table shown below, I want to delete the white spaces before the ID #, ideally using `sed`.

```
   ID,DESC,PRIORITY,
   1178896,SKIP BI UPDATE, Low
   1178900,SKIP BI UPDATE, High 
   1178901,SKIP BI UPDATE, High
```

The output should look like this:

```
ID,DESC,PRIORITY,
1178896,SKIP BI UPDATE, Low
1178900,SKIP BI UPDATE, High 
1178901,SKIP BI UPDATE, High
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426358/correct-way-to-match-a-leading-space-with-sed-all-of-them/426365

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have GNU `sed`, the following command should remove all leading whitespace:

```
sed -E 's/^\s+//' file.txt
```

or, for POSIX-compatible `sed` variants

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]\{1,\}//' file.txt
```

Comment: What's the reason for `\+` or `\{1,\}` anyways? `s/^ *//` will do the same job to remove leading whitespaces.

Comment: @Philippos Won't remove tabs though. I would have used `s/^[[:blank:]]*//`.

Comment: @Kusalananda The question asks to remove just white spaces; we don't know whether tabs are allowed to be removed, but obviously my point is the use of `*` instead of those other suggestions.